# Recompile shared Android library for Linux

Tags: android, gcc, compilation, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use an SDK (provided by a third party, not Android SDK) for Android (ARM) that implements functionality in native code, unfortunately what I'm trying to do requires a central server as well. All I have is the compiled .so file (and a jar that interfaces to it), I know this is a reach but is it possible to recompile it to run on a normal Linux (x64) box?

I figure it probably wont work cuz of differences between JNI and Android NDK interface but I thought I'd ask here before I throw in the towel on the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Android sdk contains .jar files only and no .so files.
The .so files to which .jar is linked to is already present in devices as a part of Android OS.

So for linux, compile the Android source code for x86 and you will get all the .so for x86.
Once you compile the android source code it also creates sdk for the respective architecture.

But I think .jar should be same for all architecture as java is architecture independent.

Comment: It's not the Android SDK I'm talking about, but an SDK provided by an external third party.